# Erro TFS: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, team-foundation-server

Está ocorrendo o seguinte erro ao fazer checkin no Visual studio 2013 para o VSO (TFS online):

> *Multiple errors occurred during the operation, the first of which is displayed below. A full error list is available in the Output Window.
>   c:\users\xxxx\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Turbostore\Turbostore.Domain.Test\UnitTest1.cs: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.*

Estou rodando em uma maquina Windows 8 com Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 1):

Há algumas opções para este problema ter aparecido:

- Você está com problema no servidor (não está aceitando conexão HTTPS)
- Você está com problemas na sua conexão internet ou servidor de DNS configurado na máquina cliente
- Você está tentando conectar com HTTPS num servidor que não serve TFS com HTTS e deveria ter conectado de forma comum com HTTP
- O Firewall do seu Windows ou de sua empresa pode estar bloqueando esta conexão
- Pode haver um Proxy na rede que não suporta HTTPS ou que está por algum motivo bloqueando a conexão para este servidor.

Comment: Estou utilizando o TFS online(VSO) e desabilitei o firewall. Consigo acessar o serviço do VSO normalmente pela web. Só pra complementar, quando eu faço um get specific version de uma pasta pra pegar todos os arquivos o erro acontece em alguns arquivos, mais não em todos. Se fosse um erro de conexão não poderia dar certo em alguns arquivos, correto?

Comment: @RobertoMiranda alguma evolução ou mais informações de diagnóstico?

Comment: aparentemente com a instalação do Update 1 do VS 2013 resolveu. Não ocorreu mais o erro.